# Python / google app engine self request domain

Tags: python

I know that the google app engine come with the self.request for url and the path in the python platform.

What I wanted to know is that did it come with anything to return only the domain name?

This is because sometime in the **localhost**, **mywebapps.appspot.com** and **www.mywebapps.com** will have different kind of behavior.

Or is there any python code I can referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Google app engine uses  the [CGI standard](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Requests_and_CGI), you can use `Host` header in request  from within the application code and respond accordingly.

How to access Host will depend on the web framework e.g webapp and django may differ in details, but as it is CGI you can just access os.environ from anywhere e.g.

```
import os
logging.debug("Host: %s"%os.environ['HTTP_HOST'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to answer
bu it's in the doc but quite hard to find
A request class is from webop framework
one has to follow the only link provided in App Engine doc http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html

so the anser is self.request.host_url
you'll need to remove the beginning http://